# Descend position of already sorted objects inside a JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I created a sort function that sorting the objects inside may array. Now I want to enable the user to inverse the sort if it already sorted by wanted value, but i cant get it to work.
Any help will be appreciated

```
case 'fileName':
        this.contractList.sort((a, b) => {
          const nameA = a.filename.toUpperCase();
          const nameB = b.filename.toUpperCase();

          if (nameA < nameB) {
            return this.sortedValue === 'fileName' ? -1 : 1;
          }
          if (nameA > nameB) {
            return this.sortedValue !== 'fileName' ? 1 : -1;
          }
          return 0;
        });
        this.sortedValue = 'fileName';
        break;
```

Comment: Did you try to change minority sign to opposite in if statements? if (nameA > B) ... ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions.

**First** (dirty): simply sort and `.reverse()` the array each time:

```
this.contractList.sort((a, b) => {
    const nameA = a.filename.toUpperCase();
    const nameB = b.filename.toUpperCase();

    if (nameA < nameB) {
        return this.sortedValue === 'fileName' ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if (nameA > nameB) {
        return this.sortedValue !== 'fileName' ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
})
.reverse();
```

So each time it will be sorted and reversed. Once sorted ascending, it will be sorted again (no change) and reversed (change). Another change, another sort (no change) and another reverse (change).

**Second** (better): remember the order of a last sorting (asc/desc) and depending on this value change the value from `-1` to `1`:

```
const newSorting = this.lastSortingOrder === 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
this.lastSortingOrder = this.lastSortingOrder === 'asc' ? 'desc' : 'asc';
this.contractList.sort((a, b) => {
    const nameA = a.filename.toUpperCase();
    const nameB = b.filename.toUpperCase();

    if (nameA < nameB) {
        return this.sortedValue === 'fileName' ? -1 * newSorting : newSorting;
    }
    if (nameA > nameB) {
        return this.sortedValue !== 'fileName' ? newSorting : -1 * newSorting;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Which will change the order of this sorting depending on last value of the `this.lastSortingOrder` variable;